# IMAP mail gatherer with correct behavior of setting mail as read

Tags: email, mail, imap, mbox

At first I tried `fetchmail` with the given config. The problem was that all mails in the inbox would be marked as read in IMAP server upon running `fetchmail`:

```
set postmaster danial
set no bouncemail
poll mail.tld.com protocol IMAP user "danial" there with password "secret" keep
```

Next I migrated to `getmail6` which didn't mark mails as read on run, but it didn't mark them as read after reading them locally with `mail` or `mutt` too; even with `--idle=MAILBOX` option. Here is the config:

```
[retriever]
type=SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever
server=mail.tld.com
username=danial
password=secret

[destination]
type=Mboxrd
path=/var/mail/danial

[options]
verbose=0
read_all=false
delivered_to=false
received=false
message_log_syslog=true
message_log_verbose=true
```

How can I make the read behavior correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a standard MUA like alpine, etc. to read your mail?  Is there a reason you need a special process to run that transparently/automatically?

Comment: @ThomasWard I want my mails to be merged with my local mbox in /var/mail/

Comment: Both tools you've indicated only *fetch* mail.  Fetchmail obeys IMAP syntax, that when an email is opened and fetched it removes the Unread flag.  The other simply pulls your data down.  Neither tool is capable of dual-direction sync between a local mailbox and a remote mailbox because there's no mechanisms in those tools to "sync" local against remote (especially with IMAP in play because IDs, etc. change in IMAP systems).  If your intention is to have it only be marked as read on remote when you read it locally, there is no system for that. Other than an actual mail client.